# Property 'addToast' does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers' angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

basically i have a method called "addToast" in my component.ts file. which is this :-

```
addToast(options): any {
    if (options.closeOther) {
      this.toastyService.clearAll();
    }

this.position = options.position ? options.position : this.position;

const toastOptions: ToastOptions = {
  title: options.title,
  msg: options.msg,
  showClose: options.showClose,
  timeout: options.timeout,
  theme: options.theme,
  onAdd: (toast: ToastData) => {
    /* added */
  },
  onRemove: (toast: ToastData) => {
    /* removed */
  }
};

switch (options.type) {
  case "default":
    this.toastyService.default(toastOptions);
    break;
  case "info":
    this.toastyService.info(toastOptions);
    break;
  case "success":
    this.toastyService.success(toastOptions);
    break;
  case "wait":
    this.toastyService.wait(toastOptions);
    break;
  case "error":
    this.toastyService.error(toastOptions);
    break;
  case "warning":
    this.toastyService.warning(toastOptions);
    break;
}


}
```

and i'm try to using this method to another method called "onLoadFile". which is this :-

```
onLoadFile(event) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = event.target.result;
    var isUploadPic = null;

    img.onload = function(): any {
      console.log(img.width, "x", img.height);
      // var isUploaded = false;
      if (img.width != 600 && img.height != 600) {
        this.addToast({
          title: "FAIL!",
          msg: "Diamension Should Be 600x600.",
          timeout: 6000,
          theme: "default",
          position: "top-right",
          type: "error"
        });
      }
    };

    console.log(isUploadPic);


  }
```

but it showing me an error on VSCODE, which is "Property 'addToast' does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers'". i am sharing a image of that.

[image]

and also i'm sharing the image of console ERROR. which is below.

[image]

Please tell me how can i use the "addToast" method on that position. give me a solution.

Comment: Don't use anonymous functions. Use arrow functions: `img.onload = () => { ... }`

Answer (score 30):

### Issue

You are using nested anonymous function and that is why context has been changed and `this` is point to `GlobalEventHandlers` not the Component class.

### Fix

You have two options to fix this issue

> Fix 1

The first fix to keep the reference of `this` and use it inside the anonymous function. The current context (`this`) can be assigned to some variable say `self` and can be used anywhere in deep nested functions. `this` may change however `self` will always point to the parent.

```
   let self = this;
    img.onload = function(): any {
          console.log(img.width, "x", img.height);
          // var isUploaded = false;
          if (img.width != 600 && img.height != 600) {
            self.addToast({
              title: "FAIL!",
              msg: "Diamension Should Be 600x600.",
              timeout: 6000,
              theme: "default",
              position: "top-right",
              type: "error"
            });
          }
        };
```

> Fix 2

The second option is to use arrow function. In arrow function `this` always point to the context it is called from. This is better approach than fix 1.

```
img.onload = () => {
      console.log(img.width, "x", img.height);
      // var isUploaded = false;
      if (img.width != 600 && img.height != 600) {
        this.addToast({
          title: "FAIL!",
          msg: "Diamension Should Be 600x600.",
          timeout: 6000,
          theme: "default",
          position: "top-right",
          type: "error"
        });
      }
    };
```

Comment: Using arrow function worked in my case , thanks!

Comment: Could you discuss the pros and cons of both approaches too? Thanks.